# Plots with Temperature max/min only

Tags: python, numpy, max, min

I am trying to plot temperature max/min using Python. So far I was only able to plot all the temperatures recorded for a given time. Below is the code I am using. Any suggestions to capture only Max and Min of `T_ch` (temperature in a chamber)?

```
fig905, f905ax = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=4, figsize=(16, 12))
for i in range(1, 5):
    for j, sn in enumerate(['DJF', 'MAM', 'JJA', 'SON']):
        f905ax[i - 1, j].plot(hr_local_int[(ch_no.values == i) & (season == sn)],
                              df_flux.loc[(ch_no.values == i) & (season == sn), 'T_ch' +str(i)],
                              '.', color=color_list[i - 1])
        f905ax[i - 1, j].set_xlim((-0.5, 24.))
        f905ax[i - 1, j].xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(3))
        f905ax[i - 1, j].xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
        if i == 1:
            f905ax[0, j].set_title(sn)

    f905ax[i - 1, 0].set_ylabel('ch' + str(i) + ' Temperature (C)')

for j in range(4):
    f905ax[3, j - 1].set_xlabel('Hour (PDT, UTC-7)')

fig905.tight_layout()
fig905.savefig(plot_dir + '/ch_plots/Tch_diurnal.png', dpi=300)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `numpy.amax` and `numpy.amin` functions to get the maximum and minimum value of temperature axis in the array  ( https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html#numpy.amax )

with `numpy.argmax` you can also get the index ( time ) of the max value